# How to set Google Cloud Storage setting "Share publicly" false and show a checkbox in front of filename

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

When I upload an image from my node.js application, the image is uploaded publicly since the public link is available.
I want to upload the image privately

```
const storage = Storage({
  projectId: config["googleProjectID"]
});

for (var key in CLOUD_BUCKET){
  bucketReference[key] = storage.bucket(CLOUD_BUCKET[key]); 
}
const gcsname = "your."+extension;
if(bucketReference[tag]){
    file = bucketReference[tag].file(gcsname);
  }
```

This is uploading an image with baseurl/bucket_name/your.jpeg but public link is available and anyone can see it by pasting it in url and signing in gmail.

I want to bring a checkbox instead of public link on upload (as it happens when we manually upload on storage).

Please help out in resolving this !

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer !

```
const stream = file.createWriteStream({
    metadata: {
      contentType: "image/jpeg",
    },
    predefinedAcl: "bucketOwnerRead"//shows no checkbox since project owner has reader access and no one accept object owner can see images
    predefinedAcl: "bucketOwnerFullControl" //shows a checkbox and only shows the image to those who are project owners
  });
```

"predefinedAcl" is the key.
It makes the image while upload as public or private.

This only allows the project team owners the access to make urls public or view the urls in incognito after signing in.